# How to write the Looping structure for Parent-Child relationships?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, parent-child

I am using treetable.js. as procedure i saved the child id and parent id. insert data is successfully inserted. but return data may show in table only or get the grouping error.
then i use the IGrouping Object get the Convertion error.
Please tell me the child parent loop structure for the below.

**In Model:**

```
public string name {get;set;}    
public int childId {get;set;}
public int  ParentId {get;set;}
```

**In Controller:**

```
var list = db.table.groupby(s=>s.parentId).toList();
   return view(list);
```

**In view:**

```
 <table id="example-basic">
         <tr>

             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Data Id</th>
             <th>Parent Id</th>
         </tr>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <tr data-tt-id='@item.dataid' data-tt-parent-id='@item.dataparentid'>

            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.dataid</td>
            <td>@item.dataparentid</td>
        </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

Comment: what is "the Convertion error"? or "the grouping error"?  It's easier to provide an accurate answer to your question if you list the errors you are receiving.

Comment: `ChildId` is's your row `Id`, am i get it right?

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],Project_Cost_Management_System.Models.ChartOfAccount]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project_Cost_Management_System.Models.ChartOfAccount]'.

Comment: No, id in GUID @teovankot

Answer (score 0):

If you want just get rid of exception with grouping you should write like this:

```
  var list = db.table.groupby(s => s.parentId).Select(x => new ChartOfAccount 
  { 
       ParentId = x.Key,
       childId = x.First().childId,
       name = x.First().name
  }).toList();
  return view(list);
```

As you can see you will get only one row for each `ParentId` becouse or grouping.

But i gess you searching for something else.

Comment: Get Error on `return view(list);` as `The entity or complex type 'Project_Cost_Management_System.Models.ChartOfAccount' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: @SaravananArunagiri i suppose that's becouse your entity has more properties. Don't you want just create `ViewModelChartOfAccount` class and get it in `Controller` and use on `View`?