# How to grouping for the following structure in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

**Here my table is :**

```
**Name childid Parentid** 
 Root    1        0
 child1  2        1
 child2  3        1
 child3  4        2
 child4  5        1
 child5  6        2
```

**But i want this format :**

```
 **Name childid Parentid**   
 Root    1        0
 child1  2        1
 child2  5        2
 child5  6        2
 child2  3        1
 child4  4        1
```

Simply asking how to get parent related child as down??

Give me the MVC5 controller code for that.
I use that orderby and sorting but does not working ? give me the structure using with foreach.

Comment: Can you post what you have currently done (code) because I do not understand the question. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285423/how-to-write-the-looping-structure-for-parent-child-relationships) see that post

Comment: "Give me the MVC5 controller code for that." ... yeah, that'll get you far here.